# PhpStorm - Zoom In for Non-Editor text (e.g. Menus and Tool Windows)

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am just starting to use PhpStorm (version 2021.2.2)

I can see you can easily make the text larger in the editor using ctrl mouse wheel. But is there a way to expand the general application text, e.g. as used in the menus, tool windows, project tree structure, etc?

This would be the equivalent of the View->Appearance->Zoom In option in VS Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Use custom font** -- you can specify custom font size there.

Default settings (Windows 10; no screen scaling or alike; all native 100%):
[image]

Custom font size (16):
[image]

*Click to open both images in new tabs and switch between them to compare*